# What does this Haskell data declaration means

Tags: haskell

Just started learning Haskell. Can someone be so kind to explain what this declaration means?

```
data Stream a = a :& Stream a
```

I know that it builds an infinite stream of type a, similar to what Data/Stream does, except Data/Stream uses Cons:

```
data Stream a = Cons a (Stream a)
```

But i can't figure out what `:&` means. `(:)` is a concatenation operator, but there is no `(:&)` or `(&)` operator in Haskell.

Comment: They here simply used an infix operator `:&` as data constructor. So `:&` is nothing special.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But i can't figure out what `:&` means.

Here they used `:&` as the *infix* data constructor. So instead of using `Cons` like in the data declaration you quote, you should use `:&`. An equivalent definition could have been:

```
data Stream a = (:&) a (Stream a)
```

In fact, you could see the `:` operator as just another infix data constructor.

A infix data constructor should start with a colon (`:`), as is specified in the [Haskell grammar](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html):

> ```
> consym → ( : {symbol}) ⟨reservedop⟩
> ```

Comment: so.. `:&` is a declaration of a data constructor? And since it uses only special characters it automatically becomes an infix function? I think i understand now, thank you!

Comment: @InsoReiges Yes, it's just an arbitrary name for a constructor. It could have been `Cons`, `Foo`, or `:$&$`. The only difference is that names starting with `:` are used infix instead of prefix.